# Laravel Session + Cartalyst Sentry Session Issues

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentry

on Laravel 4.2 and using Sentry 2.1, it looks like there is no way to have Sentry use the same cookie as the laravel session. Right now, the cookies for Sentry are being set for 5 years into the future by default. I don't see a way in their configs for this to change. Looking in the package code, I do see the 'forever' function, but the time is not configurable from what I can tell.

The question here is how can you maintain a user's laravel session cookie is expiring sooner than the Sentry cookie, since some features are toggled on/off in session within Laravel, and if the cookie expiration is long than the Laravel session, it will throw the system into thinking it's OK for that user to be logged in when really the Laravel session is now an entirely new session.